# The mysterious "missing endgroup" error

Tags: tables, captions, tabularx, floatrow

First, thank you to everyone for being so helpful with my posts!  Hopefully I am not getting too annoying, but I have another issue.

I am putting in nicely formatted tables.  The following code compiles; however, the caption and table number are missing AND I get the mysterious "missing end group" error.  A lot of googling indicates this is typically a package clash, but I only load a couple of packages in this MWE so...help?

```
\documentclass[class=article, crop=false]{standalone}

% Tables
\usepackage{floatrow}       % Modifying the layout of floats
\usepackage{tabularx}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top} % Caption above table
% Custom captions in floating environments
\usepackage[{font=small,sc},labelfont={bf,sc},labelsep=newline]{caption}   

%--- Table column commands with specified widths:
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}%

\begin{document}

% Treatment and Disposal Methods
\begin{table}[h!] \footnotesize
\caption{Test Table}
\label{tab:testtab} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ C{0.3} L{2.1}  L{0.6} }
\hline \hline
Reference    & Focus     & Approach\\ 
\hline
Ref1  & Overview of treatment methods
        & Literature review  \\
Ref2    & Overview of membrane methods
        & Literature review  \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `standalone`? Use just `article`.

Comment: These tables are in a section of my dissertation.  I was working on this section the last few weeks and made it into a standalone so I wouldn't have to compile the whole document (which now contains a lot of tikz pictures and takes awhile to compile).  This is from the Literature Review.  I got rid of the section headings and such to slim down the MWE.

Comment: Removing those two slashes does not remove the error and generates an additional error that \hline is being used outside a table environment. :-(

Comment: The issue is created by the `floatrow` package in the `standalone` class, I suggest that you don't use it. What do you need it for anyways? (well, or you use a different class...)

Comment: Thanks.  I think I initially added floatrow so I could easily change the caption position depending on the paper/journal/dissertation audience.  
I will leave it in the preamble and just use a different technique to compile one section at a time (having my own extra document that just compiles the section I am working on).
Out of curiosity, how did you know that was the package clash?  Neither the standalone documentation or the floatrow documentation even mention each other?